# Python CouchDB Lookup

Tags: python, couchdb

What is the best, most efficient way to look up key/values within a db.
I basically want to be able to return the document if the key/pair combo lookup is true,

```
>>> import couchdb
>>> import couchquery
>>>
>>> db = dbserver['test']
>>> dbserver = couchdb.Server()
>>>
>>> for x in db:
...     try:
...       if db[x]["foo"] == "bar":
...         db[x]
...     except:
...         pass
...
```

This is what I have so far, but Im sure there must be a better way ...

Thanks,

Comment: i think you do not need the ¸import couchquery¸

Answer (score 0):

2 scenarios:

### Your Value in the database is a dictionary

e.g.

```
'db_key': {foo:bar}
```

The code you are running will work if you don't know the `db_key` parameter and want to know check the dictionary in the `db_value`.

### You want to check if the database value matches your expected value

I don't think you need the `for` loop. Do the following:

```
expected_value = "bar"
key = "foo"
found_value = db[key]

if found_value == expected_value:
    print(key, expected_value)
```